# EXT fields in CDDB

Tags: mp3, abcde

What are the EXT fields in CDDB used for?

I'm inputting the information for a new CD into CDDB as part of running abcde.
In addition to the regular track info it includes a series of entries:

```
EXTD=
EXTT0=
EXTT1=
EXTT2=
EXTT3=
EXTT4=
EXTT5=
```

What would/should/could someone put into these fields for the CDDB database?

Comment: There is no standard for extended tags.

Comment: The question appears to be about CDDB tags, not about MP3 tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On occasion you may run into something you want recorded but not in the song title. Song Composer, featured musician, Medley list or alternate song title.

Really just anything extra apparently.